# Flutter app in production is not writing data to firebase anymore

Tags: flutter, firebase

I have a Flutter app in production, he was working well in debug mode. I could write data to firebase without any issue. When released to production, I also could read and write to firebase. Suddenly, the app is not behaving well anymore, when I post data to firebase, it is not writing any data at all but when I modified data directly from firebase, it gets updated in the app. Anybody can help me with this issue?

Answer (score 1):

This might be because of the temporary Cloud Firestore rules you have set up in the beginning.

Go to **Firebase** -> **Firestore Database** -> **Rules**;

[image]

in here you should be able to see the restrictions to who can write or read from your Firestore databse, **or until when your users can** write/read to your database.

If you just want authenticated users to Read&Write whenever they want you can use this sample;

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

If you want to create a custom rule you can check the [Cloud Firestore Security documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started).

Comment: Thanks bro for your response. I have the same rules you just showed on the exemple. I have implemented AppCheck on my project and it seems solving the issue. I am now able to read and write again.